# Hector Slam input IMU data

Tags: ros, hector-slam, xv-11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am running hector_slam in ROS Hydro with a Neato XV-11 laser and a Razor 9dof IMU.

The IMU has been included via hector_imu_attitude_to_tf.

In RViz everything looks good, I have a base_footprint frame that only moves on X and Y (and yaw) and attached to it a base_link frame that has additional roll and pitch movement.

Now my question is this:

Right now the IMU data is only transforming a frame but I guess that has no direct effect on the computation of hector_slam? Do I have to specify somewhere that hector_slam should consider the IMU data to increase its own accuracy? Or do I have to run an additional node for that, like hector_localization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198636/hector-slam-input-imu-data/) by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hector_slam only uses (roll/pitch) imu data implicitly by transforming the scan through tf. It would be possible to for example use IMU data for improving the scan-matching start estimate, but this is currently not implemented.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) on 2014-12-02**:
Ok thanks!

**Comment by [wyasuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/10211/wyasuda/) on 2015-01-01**:
Dear Stefan,
I have a question about this issue.
I read the pdf below.
http://tedusar.eu/cms/sites/tedusar.eu.cms/files/Hector_SLAM_USAR_Kohlbrecher_RRSS_Graz_2012.pdf
On page 32, you explained the Handheld Mapping System has IMU.
Does IMU has no direct effect on the computation of hector_slam?